# MATLAB: Tracking the direction of a spacecraft - loss of precision

Tags: matlab, vector, direction

Imagine you have a target direction that we call " dir " , a unitary vector centred in Earth. Now, you have the trajectory of the spacecraft that is travelling to the boundary of the solar system, and each position is given in a heliocentric frame ( see image). You just want to know if the spacecraft is keeping the target direction " dir ". Imagine that nothing is moving except the spacecraft. Then, for each heliocentric position you do the following thing:

r_A = r-r_Earth

Where r_A is the geocentric position vector just for the first point, then you should do it for each point. So you compute the direction of r_A and you compare it with "dir".

Important: we imagine no forces are acting on the s/c, so the trajectory is straight.

It seems easy, but when the s/c go far and far away from the Sun, r becomes bigger and bigger, and the operation " r-r_Earth" can bring to loss of significance errors. Imagine that we quantify the errors between the actual direction and the target direction as angles between them, these angles start from 0 and then they reach values of 10^-4. This shouldn't happen since the trajectory is straight, no deviation should be observed. If you need, I can send you a small code of this problem. Thank you very much for your help guys. [[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN7hn.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfiuJ.jpg)

I expect to have always a 0 error in direction.

Comment: What programming language are you using and what data types?

Comment: MATLAB, I am using just vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're losing precision because of round-off errors due to the values of `r` becoming bigger. My guess would be on round-off errors due to the limited digits of precision Matlab uses for it's doubles.

One option to avoid round-off errors is to switch to symbolic calculations using Matlab's Symbolic Math Toolbox, see [this article on increasing precision](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/increase-precision-of-numeric-calculations.html) and [this one covering round-off errors](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/recognize-and-avoid-roundoff-errors.html).

Another idea would be to change the units of `r`, e.g. to AU or something custom. But I guess this depends on the level of precision you need.